# How can my form submit a text value using a <select>?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

To summarize a whole lot and describe the situation, I have a form with drop down menus and textboxes. Basically what I am trying to do is this:

My form has drop down menus, but when I submit it, it should submit the value as if the drop down menu was a textbox. It's hard to explain.

So basically I am POSTing to a link which uses a servlet API to take the form fields submitted and fill out a ticket. Now the problem is that crappy Servlet API doesn't support drop down menus, only text boxes. Basically it means I can't submit a drop down menu, only a text box.

My possible solution is: let the user pick in the form what item they want from a drop down menu. In the code there would be something, maybe PHP, inside the HTML that will say if user has chosen option 1 in drop down menu then SET textbox B's value to "General", if user has chosen option 2 in drop down menu then SET textbox D's value to "Production", etc.

I don't really know how to do this or what to do. All I know is that the drop down menu's chosen option MUST be submitted as a textbar's value in order for the Servlet API to use that form field for a ticket. Any ideas? The user wouldn't see this textbox because it would be hidden and in the backend.

http://jsfiddle.net/MwnSn/16/

Comment: The title should summarize your problem, not be random words and an emoticon.

Comment: Translation: `textbar` or `textbox` means `input type=text`; `drop down menu` means `single option select box`. Servlet API????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
<select name="myfield">
   <option value="somevalue">Descriptive Text</option>
</select>
```

and this:

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" value="somevalue" />
```

will both produce exactly the same data when submitted: `myfield=somevalue`. A script/servlet/whatever receiving this data has absolutely no way of telling if the data came from a select field or an input field.

So basically, generate your `<select>`  box using the same data in the value section as for the descriptive text:

```
 <option value="dataA">dataA</option>
 <option value="dataB">dataB</option>
 etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you almost have it, instead of using `<option value="0">`, just use `<option value="Access Request">`.

Of course, you *should* have something in PHP making sure that it is a valid text, so you might be better off leaving it as is and then pulling the text from a database or by looking it up in an array. Eg:

```
$myFields = array(
   0 => 'Access Request'
);

$usrField = $myFields[ $_POST[ 'myfield' ] ];
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more I can't quite visualize your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript.

```
            function getSelectedvalue(){   
                var getSelectedIndex = document.FORM-NAME.SELECT-ID.selectedIndex;
                var getSelectedOptionText = document.FORM-NAME.INPUT-ID.[getSelectedIndex].value;
                // IF value = 0
                if (getSelectedOptionText == '0') {
                        document.getElementById('INPUT-ID').value = 'Production';
                    }
                // If value = 1
                .....
                // If value = 1
                .....
            }
```

Then put  `onchange="getSelectedvalue()"` on the `selectbox`.

Hope it Helps!